# Class not found exception in design time

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I have written a date control with a button but in design time it wont draw. Error log contains the following. Would appreciate any help as I am stumped.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:102)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
```

...

Comment: Please post relevant sections of your code so that people can find the problem

Answer (score 1):

:) Have you tried out to build your application ! :) I don't Have idea about android but in-case of java when I face such type of error i just try to build/restart my application + i restart my server (glassfish, apache--- what ever you use) Try this will be fine definitely :) Thank You ! Have a great day !